# update spinner array depend on other's selection

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
Spinner spinner, spinner2;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_check_box_tuts);

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> v, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner1:
            if(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1){
                //what goes here??
            break;
        }
        }
    }
```

Like my first spinner lists are countries : USA, JAPAN etc.. so after USA has been selected for example, my second spinner would able to get a list of USA's state array..

I use my newbie logic to try to think this way : set the 2nd spinner to View.GONE, then if lets say USA is selected, show the spinner2 which it alone carry the states.. but if I have 60 countries, then I must have 60 spinner, that's funny so help me :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating a `Spinner` for each country instance, keep the same `Spinner`, and replace the data stored in it when a value is selected from your first `Spinner` with 
[ArrayAdapter.createFromResource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#createFromResource%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29) and [Spinner.setAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setAdapter%28T%29). [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) is an example using those two calls.

Rather than hiding your second `Spinner` before an option is selected in the first, consider having a default selection in the first `Spinner`, and populating the second with the matching data. In your example, USA would be a good default selection.

Comment: `public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> v, View arg1, int arg2,
   long arg3) {
  
  int pos = country.getSelectedItemPosition();
  switch(pos){
   case 0: stateSpinner.setEnabled(false);
   break;
   
   case 1:
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
               R.array.US_state_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       stateSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
       break;`

the second array update but cannot be selected.. WHY?